# Find android SDK path from c# win desktop (Where android studio store data like AndroidSDK path)

Tags: c#, windows, android-studio

Conditional:
- Android SDK can be placed any where. Can be on different hdd partition.
- User have installed Android Studio.

Is there any posibillity to find android SDK path from androidStudio [installed] data.

Android Studio must have place where put saved path. Maybe win register or some internal files. Maybe ENV VARS .

I just need information where can be saved path - i know how to read files or register...

Any suggestion?